# ...how it reacts, adding to the difficulty

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-clauses

'Also, the wind can significantly alter the direction of the ship and how it reacts, adding to the difficulty of anchoring the ship.'

1. What does "it" refer to in 'how it reacts,...?
2. What is the subject of the clause of 'adding to the difficulty of..."? How should the sentence be rewritten if one doesn't use 'adding to...'?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: **It** refers to the ship. What original sentence are you referring to?

Comment: It unclear to me what point 2 is asking.

Comment: Sentence containing the basic assertion: *Also, the wind can significantly alter the direction of the ship and how it reacts.* Which could be followed by a complete *additional* sentence: ***This adds** to the difficulty of anchoring the ship.* Where "this" refers to the entire preceding sentence (i.e. - ***the fact of** the wind doing this **adds** to the difficulty*).